# ng-model not capturing default value from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a value passed from the controller as shown below

```
var ndata = {                   
    id:res.data.data.id,
    option1:res.data.data.option1,
    option2:res.data.data.option2              
};


$rootScope.vars = ndata;
```

Now the above has a value and I am getting it to the view and assigned to an input field

```
<label>dec</label>
<input ng-model="vars.option1" data-ng-change="nd.option1=vars.option1"
       placeholder="select" type="text"
       class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

if I submit the above form, the model nd.options is having null unless I enter additional value to the input field. Which means it is not initialized with the default value in the controller

Comment: What does `{vars | json}` show on your page?

Comment: the actual data from the controller

Comment: I don't see `nd.options` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It will show the result that you expect.

Kindly check the below code snippet:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.name = 'World';

var ndata = {
            id:'001',
            option1:'Option1',
            option2:'Option2'
    };

  $scope.vars = ndata;
 $scope.SubmitForm=function(){
alert(ndata.option1);
}
});
```

> > AND in the html file write:

```
<label>dec</label>
<input ng-model="vars.option1" data-ng-
  change="nd.option1=vars.option1" placeholder="select" type="text" 
  class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
<input type="submit" ng-click="SubmitForm()">

>> Kindly check the Plunker link for more information:
```

[Link] https://plnkr.co/edit/wkDSGZwGCGDtpVz49r0u?p=preview

Comment: clicking the button nothing happens. You have made any chages

Comment: @rocket -- kindly check now. the module name is changed there. in Plunker code. [Link] https://plnkr.co/edit/wkDSGZwGCGDtpVz49r0u?p=preview

Comment: try to alert this nd.option1

Comment: @rocket  what is nd?

Comment: nd is an array that holds all the input variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172763/discussion-between-rocket-and-hanmant-rachmale).